# Изменение цвета определённого текста в java

Tags: java, android, textview, color

Доброе время суток, как можно изменить определённый текст в android studio.
Для примера, есть код, написан как текст в TextView:

```
new, void, switch ....
true, false....
```

У меня текст очень большой и считать каждый элемент для работы со спаном очень проблемно.

Вот например есть книга и нужно выделить слова **дом**, **дача** одним цветом. Есть ли альтернатива кода типа if-else или же с циклом для подставления цвета для определённого текста.
Я представляю это так:

```
if(text.equals("Дом")){
//заменить цвет?
}
```

Comment: @woesss, где вы были, гуглил, а не нашёл

Comment: Саму книгу нельзя заготовить сразу с html-разметкой? Если нет, то вам нужно в цикле искать все вхождения слов/фраз и выделять их спанами.

Comment: Дмитрий, в указанном вам вопросе содержится решение вашей проблемы. Другого нет.

Comment: @МихаилРебров, у меня нету идей как с циклом слепить

Comment: @DmitriyParkhomenko, тогда, очевидно, вам нужно задать другой вопрос. Ибо как изменить цвет определенного текста в ответе указано. Если Вы не понимаете как что-то обработать в цикле, то постарайтесь это сформулировать в другом вопросе... Но на данный момент я лично не особо могу что-то подсказать, поскольку на данный момент мне совершенно непонятно в чем у вас возникает сложность. И если Вы ровно с такой же формулировкой придете к сообществу, то боюсь остальные тоже вас не поймут.  Вам нужно постараться описать свой затык.